# XGBClassifier gives 100% accuracy on test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm triying to make a model to predict the hazardness of an asteroid using a NASA dataset.
The dataset by itself doesn't have any null values. After eliminated irrelevant features such as ids, i only had a few categorical columns that were datetimes. So i splitted the data 80-train and 20-test this way:

```
X_train, X_test= np.split(X, [int(.80 *len(X))])
y_train, y_test= np.split(y, [int(.80 *len(X))])
```

Then i made a personalized transformer to process the dates, creating new columns for day, month and year, and eliminating the original date feature from the data:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

class DateProcessor(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, documents, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, df):
        dateCols = ['Close Approach Date', 'Orbit Determination Date']
        new_df = df.copy()
        for col in dateCols:
        
            new_df[col] = pd.to_datetime(new_df[col], errors="coerce",format="%Y-%m-%d")
            #df.dropna(axis=1, subset=['date'], inplace=True)
        
            newColsDict = {'day': str(col) + " day", 'month': str(col) + " month", 'year': str(col) + " year"}
            new_df[newColsDict['day']] = new_df[col].dt.day
            new_df[newColsDict['month']] = new_df[col].dt.month
            new_df[newColsDict['year']] = new_df[col].dt.year
        
        new_df.drop(inplace=True, columns=dateCols)
        return new_df
```

After that, i made a pipeline to preprocess the data and then train it using a XGBClassifier:

```
estimator = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1)
model_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
                                ('process_dates', DateProcessor()),
                                ('XGBoost', estimator)
                                ])
model_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After the training, every scoring metric i try, gives 100% accuracy. I'm not very experienced on AI, but i thought that 100% accuracy on test data is usually indicating there's a problem?
I dont really know if there's some kind of data leakage, data contamination or something like that.
PD: i also tried using normal train_test_split (i had similar results), but i read in a post here that it wasn't correct because of the ordered-nature of the datetime features.

I will leave the link to the full code in my github repository: [NASA Asteroids Classification Model](https://github.com/juanchate/NASA-Asteroids-Classification-Model)

Comment: welcome to SO. I think the error is related to the `train-test-split` section. Try the `train_test_split()` without the time-based feature that you created. Also, can you update your Github ipython notebook to show the `head` and summary statistics on the dataset after feature engineering.

Comment: sklearn has a function specifically for [time series split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html). You should also check for data leakage between your features and targets

Comment: I made changes on my "Experimental" branch. I deleted the time-based features, used train_test_split, added `X_train.head(10)` `X_train.info()` and  `X_train.describe()`. I still got 100% accuracy on test data. I also noticed that if i dont use random_state i get different results each time, going from 99.5% to 100%

Comment: Consider 2 things: (1) if your dataset highly imbalanced? (2) shuffle your data prior to splitting